# Converting Degrees Angle to Rotation Matrix C#

Tags: c#, matrix, rotation, xyz

Basically I need to take the rotation of an object (X, Y and Z rotation) and convert it to a rotation matrix in C#. Basically what https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/ does except I'm not using three.js.

I've got the degrees value to a radian value, and have also converted that value to quaternion, but now I am stuck on how to get this into a rotation matrix form.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about  http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToMatrix/index.htm

Comment: How would I go about doing -Cos in C# tho?

Comment: How about [Math.Cos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cos?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: _"Insufficient data for meaningful answer"_  - Isaac Asimov. Any code to show?  See [faq] and [ask]

Comment: @AxelKemper that does normal cos, i need minus cos

Answer (score 0):

```
rotation3 r = rotation3.fromXyz(12, 45, 60);  //(in degree)
var m = r.getMatrix();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).